# Get two attributes using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i've a problem using Jquery.

This is my html markup:

```
 <li><a class="" value="short" tool="car" type="monov"> text </a></li>
```

I have to capture, after selecting an LI, "ttol" and "type" attr.

This is my code:

```
var selectedTool = $(this).attr('tool');
var selectedType = $(this).attr('type');
```

But it doesn't work, it arrives undefined...But if i use this:

```
$(this).html();
```

i get:

```
<li><a class="" value="short" tool="car" type="monov"> text </a></li>
```

How can i get these attributes?

Thanks

Comment: try  $(this).find("a").attr("tool")

Comment: it works! Many thanks! What i did wrong?

Comment: check answer below if it help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try below code :

```
    var $anchor = $(this).find("a");
    var selectedTool = $anchor.attr('tool');
    var selectedType = $anchor.attr('type');
```

you were trying to access the attributes of li and the attributes 'tool' and 'type' are on anchor so it was coming undefined.

Answer (score 2):

You are selecting the `<li>` when you want to select `<a>`.

Please try this:

```
var element = $(this).find("a");

var selectedTool = element.attr('tool');
var selectedType = element.attr('type');
```

Comment: This looks better because it keeps the selector instead of finding of every time.

Answer (score 0):

This code isn't going to work properly when you have multiple `<a>` tags.

Ideally, you'll have to add a unique identifier in the form of an id to each a tag. Alternatively, you could give it a class name , and identify one of the element based on it's index.

```
 <li><a class="" id="carOne"  value="short" tool="car" type="monov"> text </a></li>
```

You can then use JQuery to get the attributes like this:

```
$("#carOne").attr('tool');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to first select all a tags in li tags. Then get the attr value.

You can try:

```
$("li a").attr('tool');
$("li a").attr('type');
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this. its working fine, Just click on li item in my fiddle you can get those attr values as alerts

```js
$("li").click(function(e) { 
    
  var selectedTool = $(this).find("a").attr('tool');
  var selectedType = $(this).find("a").attr('type');
  alert(selectedTool);
  alert(selectedType);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="active" tool="car" type="monov" >Home</a></li>
           
        </ul>
```